# How can I open a file as a Http link

Tags: http, hyperlink, directory

I want to open a file in the folder (**/root/Desktop/HTMLFiles/sample.html**) as **http://localhost/HTMLFiles/sample.html**. I'm using a Linux machine.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place HTMLFiles under your webroot. If you dont wnat to do that check https://serverfault.com/questions/295975/add-a-directory-to-the-apache-web-root

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly have python installed. I would use the simple HTTP server bundled with Python:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Just navigate to the directory you want to serve files from and run that command.

You will be able to see the content at http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://localhost:8000